# how to change the speed of a function that periodically repeats itself (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

so for my end of year programming project, I was making a platformer using javascript. The main gimmick is that a magnet is periodically pulling you towards it, and you have to catch orbs; pretty simple. Since the magnet is turning off and on, I have a function that dictates when it acts and when it doesn't.

```
let attractStart = Date.now();
let gameOver = false;
function attract(){

let now = Date.now();
let delta = now - attractStart;
if(delta > 2000){
    p.moveTOmagnet();
    attractStart = Date.now();
}
if( !gameOver){
    requestAnimationFrame(attract);
}
}
attract();
```

This works as intended, but to increase challenge, I wanted the time the magnet activates to change based on how many orbs you catch. I tried replacing the 2000 with a variable that would be dependent on the number of orbs acquired (which I have counter that keeps track of that) so something like...

```
var time = 2000/(orbNum+1);
```

This did not work, even though orbNum is constantly increasing and my attract function runs constantly. Any one know how to implement this?

Also I am pretty new to stackoverflow, so I am open to suggestion on how I should word my question/ what type of question to make ^^

Comment: @Taplaar I can confirm that the first snippet DOES repeat. I am still new to javascript, but from what I gathered, 'delta' is constantly changing due to the time difference of 'attractstart' and 'now', and once it exceeds 2000, the magnet acts and 'attractstart' is reset.  The function calls itself again if it is not gameover. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Hey man, don't worry!

Answer (score 0):

This function calls itself, which doesn't really give you control over the frequency.  You should try using `setInterval` to control the repetition instead:

```js
function attract(){

  let now = Date.now();
  let delta = now - attractStart;
  if(delta > 2000){
    p.moveTOmagnet();
    attractStart = Date.now();
  }
}


setInterval( () => {
    if( !gameOver){
      requestAnimationFrame(attract);
    }
  }, 
  <frequency in milliseconds> 
)
```

This may need to be tweaked a little to get it running as intended

Comment: I have the same problem as before ;_;